# On group varieties and numbers

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, number-theory, finite-groups, universal-algebra

Suppose $\mathfrak{U}$ is a group variety. Let’s define $N_{\mathfrak{U}} \subset \mathbb{N}$ as a such set of numbers, that for any finite group $G$, $|G| \in N_{\mathfrak{U}}$ implies $G \in \mathfrak{U}$.

Examples:

If $\mathfrak{O}$ is the variety of all groups, then $N_{\mathfrak{O}} = \mathbb{N}$.

If $\mathfrak{B}_m$ is the variety of all groups of exponent $m$, then $N_{\mathfrak{B}_m}$ is the set of all divisors of $m$

If $\mathfrak{N}_c$ is the variety of all groups of nilpotency class $c$, then $N_{\mathfrak{N}_c}$ is the set of all numbers $n=p_1^{e_1}\cdots p_m^{e_m}$ with $p_i^k\not\equiv 1(\mod p_j)$ for $i,j\in\{1,\ldots,m\}$ and $1\leqslant k\leqslant e_i$, and $e_i \leq c + 1$ for $i\in\{1,\ldots,m\}$.

If $\mathfrak{U}$ and $\mathfrak{V}$ are two varieties, then $N_{\mathfrak{U}\cap\mathfrak{V}} = N_{\mathfrak{U}} \cap N_{\mathfrak{V}}$

My question is:

> Does there exist some number-theoretic characterisation of all such subsets $N \subset \mathbb{N}$, such that $N = N_{\mathfrak{U}}$ for some variety $\mathfrak{U}$?

Any $N_{\mathfrak{U}}$ satisfies the property:

> If $a \in N_{\mathfrak{U}}$ and $b | a$, then $b \in N_{\mathfrak{U}}$

Suppose $|G| = b$ and $G \notin \mathfrak{U}$. Then $G \times C_{\frac{a}{b}} \notin \mathfrak{U}$.

> If $\exists n \in \mathbb{N}$, such that $\forall k \in \mathbb{N}$ $n^k \in N_{\mathfrak{U}}$, then $\mathfrak{U} = \mathfrak{O}$.

By previous lemma, we can assume without loss of generality, that $n = p$ is prime. The only variety, that contains all $p$-groups for a fixed prime $p$ is $\mathfrak{O}$

However, I am not sure, whether those two conditions are sufficient to characterise all such sets or not.

This question was inspired by [this MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/143653/110691)

Comment: By “group variety”, you just mean “class of groups”, right? There is a notion of [group variety](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_variety) in algebraic geometry, but they don’t have groups as elements, so this is a bit confusing to me. It would be better to speak of “varieties of groups”, I think …

Comment: I am a bit confused by your example concerning the groups with exponent $m$. First of all an arbitrary finite direct product  $C_m^{n}$ of copies of a cyclic group $C_m$ of order $m$ has exponent $m$ and thus  $m^n \in N_{\mathfrak{B}_m}$ which is not a divisor of $m$ unless $n = 1$. This also seems to contradict your third highlighted statement. Also, if $m \neq 1$, then $1 \notin N_{\mathfrak{B}_m}$ which contradicts your second highlighted statement. I might be overlooking something.

Comment: @k.stm group variety is a universal algebra concept. The equations are laws in group theory, like $xy=yx$, or $x^3=1$, and the elements of the variety are all groups whose evaluation of the equations hold, in those examples abelian groups and groups of exponent 3 respectively.  Varieties in this sense date to the 1930s.

Comment: @Algeboy Thanks. However, I still think it would be less confusing to switch to “variety of groups” here, even though the name “group variety” for this notion might be old, as you insinuate. But – if it’s a name still in use – well, then that’s just the way it is, I suppose.

Comment: @k.stm.  In my experience there are enough context clues to distinguish whether its algebraic groups or universal algebra; so, I doubt the communities will concede to new naming conventions.  Both perspectives have active research communities to this today.

Comment: @Algeboy Yes, I already accepted this. Slightly sad, but no bigige.

Comment: @MatthiasKlupsch: The collection is supposed to be the numbers such that *any* group of that order will lie in the class. For $\mathcal{B}_m$, the quantity $m^n$ does not have the property because there are groups of order $m^n$ that do not lie in $\mathcal{B}_m$. A group of order $k$ will *necessarily* lie in $\mathcal{B}_m$ if and only if $k$ divides $m$; for any other quantity, there are groups of that order that do not lie in $\mathcal{B}_m$ (though there may be some groups of that order that *do*).

Comment: I see my mistake, but I don't understand your argument about the divisors of $m$. A group of order $k$ has exponent at most $k$. If $k$ is a proper divisor of $m$ its exponent is not going to be $m$. So $N_{\mathfrak{B}_m}$ would be $\{m\}$ as far as I can see.

Comment: @Matthias Klupsch, suppose $|G| | m$. Then for any subgroup $H$ of $G$, $|H| | |G|$ by Lagrange theorem. That implies that $|H| | m$. So $\forall g \in G$ we have $|\langle g \rangle| | m$, which is equivalent to $g^m = e$.

Comment: @YaniorWeg: It is clear that $g^m = e$ for all $g \in G$ when $|G|$ divides $m$. However, the exponent of a group is the smallest $n$ such that $g^n = e$ for all $g \in G$. In particular, $exp(G)$ divides $|G|$ and if $|G|$ is a proper divisor of $m$, then $m$ will not be the exponent of $G$.

Comment: @MatthiasKlupsch, when we speak about group varieties, the smallest variety that contains all groups of exponent $m$ contains also all groups, whose exponents divide $m$. However, this misunderstanding is probably my fault: I should have explicitly stated, that $\mathfrak{B}_n$ contains a group $G$ iff $\forall g \in G g^m = e$.

Comment: @YaniorWeg : I see, thanks for clearing this up.

Answer (score 2):

This is not an answer, but an observation. You have already done enough work to answer the restricted form of the question where *variety of groups* is replaced with *variety of abelian groups*.

Any proper variety of abelian groups is axiomatized by the laws of abelian groups together with  $x^m = 1$ for some $m$. Thus if $\mathfrak{U}$ is a variety of abelian groups, then $N_{\mathfrak{U}}$ must equal the set of all positive integers or else the set of divisors of $m$ for some positive $m$.

Comment: I think, you have misunderstood the definition. $N_{\mathfrak{U}}$ contains all such numbers $n$, that **any** group of order $n$ lies in $\mathfrak{U}$. So $N_{\mathfrak{U}}$ in your specific case can not be equal to $\mathbb{N}$, because finite nonabelian groups do exist. However, the contents of the OP is indeed enough to achieve a correct answer in this particular case, because all your varieties are of the form $\mathfrak{B}_n \cap \mathfrak{N}_1$.

Comment: No, I think you misunderstood my comment. As I wrote, I am referring to  the restricted form of the question where *variety of groups* is replaced with *variety of abelian groups*.

Comment: If so, then everything is OK. If we are considering only abelian groups, then your statement is indeed absolutely correct. Sorry for misunderstanding.